# Why i dont get data from database with sping boot-jpa?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I created a model class, called user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "username")
private String username;
@Column(name = "created", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime created;
@Column(name = "updated", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP")
private LocalDateTime updated;
}
```

controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public List<User> getUserList(){
    System.err.println("Get user list");
    List<User> all = userRepository.findAll();
    System.err.println("all = " + all);
    return all;
}
}
```

My properties file:

```
 spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydatabase? serverTimezone=UTC
 spring.datasource.username=root
 spring.datasource.password=root
 spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
 spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
 spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=true
 spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

In postman I send a get request to: localhost:8080/user, the first system error shows...hibernate show the sql, but i dont get the users. I tried just pass back a String, and it works correctly. If i want to user:  `userRepository.findAll()`  it is just loading...but do nothing. in the repository file i use  the extends from jparepository. 
What can be a problem? Thanks for the helps!

Comment: You say `first system error` but you don't specify or include any error nor stack trace.  It'd be helpful to include that information so that answers can be adequately constrained to help guide you to a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without logs from Spring and/or Hibernate its hard to guess but I'll post some possible reasons based on the code you provided:

1. Are you actually using MySQL Connector/J in version 8.0? In older Versions (5.1) the correct Driver class was `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, 8.0 changed it to `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.
2. Do you have the MySQL Connector/J dependency explicitly defined in your build tool (maven or gradle)? Spring will not pull it in by default, just recommend a version for it.
3. You have an extra whitespace in your JDBC URI, don't know exactly if this will work.
4. I would recommend to use the `java.sql.Timestamp` class for temporal values in entities instead of the Java 8 `DateTime` types. The Java 8 types lead to a lot of problems with ORM solutions. You can convert between Java 8 `Instant` objects and `Timestamp` objects directly. These will be stored as number (e.g. `bigint`) in your database, thus the column definition is no longer required.